# How can Maggie James remember Enzo was killed by Damon in fire in whitmore house?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-vampire-diaries

In *The Vampire Diaries* Enzo compels Maggie to forget all about him, told here to leave the place and never come back.
But in last third episode of season 5 Maggie tries to kill Damon. How can she remember all things?

Comment: I think she didn't remember but was just investigating and the clues led her to Damon.

Comment: May be but not sure because she was in mood of revenge for killing enzo that shows she had feelings for him. @madmada